# how does import statement work in react without specifying the path information in import statement as module imports cannot have a bare path

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A lot of examples use the syntax `import React, { Component } from 'react';` to import React class which should be a default export in a module exported from a file with name `react`. However it is a rule that import statements need to have a path information like `./react` in it and cannot be bare. Is webpack or some other library being used to make this work ?

Comment: Don't know why this was down voted. Don't have the complete answer but I think that is how Javascript import statements works in general and this has anything to do with react in particular. I think the path info is provided in package.json for the module. I think we can also do imports by custom module name without paths if we have a correctly configured package.json for our custom module

Comment: will try to check

Comment: Yes, `import 'react'` is illegal syntax in EcmaScript. That is unless browser vendors agree on something like [Import Maps](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps)